# scarcely any or scarcely the?

Tags: definite-article, quantifiers

In the following sentence from *Frankenstein*, the definite article "the" cannot be replaced by "any." Could anyone provide a *logical* explanation, please?

> Last Monday (July 31st), we were nearly surrounded by ice, which closed in the ship on all sides, **scarcely** leaving her **the** sea-room in which she floated. Our situation was somewhat dangerous, especially as we were compassed round by a very thick fog.

Answer (score 2):

*The* is used instead of *any* because the sentence refers to a specific amount of space among the ice; just enough for the ship to remain afloat. She had hardly any more space than that.

Compare *I had hardly any room. I had hardly the room in which to turn round.*

Comment: But generally speaking, "any" and a defining relative clause are not incompatible with each other. Cf. "  He should even accede to some of the noble lord's motions, as they called for scarcely any information which was not already before the House." https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=Lps9AAAAcAAJ&pg=RA2-PA187&dq=%22scarcely+any+information+which%22&hl=zh-TW&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_7I6-rLPqAhXIwosBHaqCAboQ6AEwAnoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22scarcely%20any%20information%20which%22&f=false

Comment: "Scarcely any space that was available to John was clean,." is also correct.

Comment: I didn't say they weren't correct; I was explaining the logic of _Scarcely... the_.

Comment: Does "space that was available to John" refer to a specific amount of space?

Comment: Not knowing the context - presumably John had been allotted a certain amount of space, and scarcely any _of it_ was clean.

Comment: Is it necessary to use "scarcely any of the space was clean" instead of "scarcely any space that was available was clean"?

Comment: Well, I would prefer to say it that way, but I won't go so far as to say that the other way is wrong. Less clear, perhaps?

Comment: I suppose "we were nearly surrounded by ice, which closed in the ship on all sides, scarcely leaving her **any** sea-room in which she floated" would still sound wrong if changed to "we were nearly surrounded by ice, which closed in the ship on all sides, leaving her scarcely  **any of the** sea-room in which she floated," isnt it?

Comment: What's wrong with the way Mary Shelley expressed it? The meaning is '...scarcely _any more room_ than the sea-room in which she floated.'

Comment: Shelley's version is correct. I'm asking about the version in which "any of the" is used. Is it incorrect?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110226/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-apollyon).